# Uploading archive to another developer iTunes Account

Tags: app-store-connect

I have admin access as an Independent Contractor to 'Suzies' account.

I have all the certificates, and distribution provisioning created.

I have a new iTunes Game in the prepare to Upload state on 'Suzies' account.

But I am unable to archive the code on my machine and successfully upload it to Suzies iTunes account.

I can archive and upload the code just fine to my iTunes Account.

Is this possible?  Any guidance would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to
1.From you keychain access generate certificate request
2.Save that request some where
3.Go to Suzie's Developer account
4.Create one new certificate with the request
5.Install it in your system
6.Make and app store Profile with this certificate in Developer.apple.com
7.Using this certificate and profile make one binary 
8.Make the status of the app upload ready to upload in Suzie's account
9.Now you will be able to up-load the binary through application loader in your system